# Value in the list is null. ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to go back from the *Create Page* to the *Index Page* which is in the Database and it still does not have any data.

This is the code in index page:

```
@if (Model.Books.Count() > 0 )
    {
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr class="table-secondary">
                <th>
                    <label asp-for="Books.FirstOrDefault().Name"></label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => a.Books.FirstOrDefault().Author)
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label asp-for="Books.FirstOrDefault().ISBN"></label>
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var data in Model.Books)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(a => data.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(a => data.Author)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*using html helper to display the data*@
                        @Html.DisplayFor(a=>data.ISBN)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <p class="text-center text-danger">No Book Available.<br /><b>Please create a book !!</b></p>
    }
```

When it is directly from *Home* to the *Index Page* it will go to the `else` statement , but from *Create Page* to the *Index* , an error is occurred.

I would like to know how to handle this exception or this error ?
I think it is not practical to develop without any dummy data but just for knowledge.

Is there any idea ?

Comment: You must check for @if (Model !=null && Model.Books.Count() > 0 ) so when navigating from other pages if model is not filled these following set of code doesn't run.

Comment: if Books is null, Model.Books.Count() will throw exception.
use Model?.Books?.Count() to void throw exception

Comment: Thanks @J.Hsu the code works, i note that

Answer (score 3):

Your first if statement gives null reference exception when the model is null or Model.Books is null.

change `@if (Model.Books.Count() > 0 )`
to

```
 @if (Model?.Books?.Count() > 0 )
```